# PHP mysqli cannot output the table when only one row returned

Tags: php, mysqli

Try to generate the generic table without the need to specify column names as the names are taken care in the select statement.  The below code works fine when zero or more than 1 row is returned by the select statement, but only print the table head when there is exactly 1 row returned.

Your advice is appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
$qry1 = "SELECT distinct subject.code as 'subject', subject.name as 'course', event.event_desc as 'description' FROM applicant, event, subject, part where applicant.applicant_id = $m_id and applicant.event_id = event.id and event.subject_id=subject.id and part.id = subject.owner_id and part.id = $p_id order by event.active DESC, event.from_month DESC ";

$result = mysqli_query($bd, $qry1);

$finfo = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);

$outp = '<div><table><tr>';
$i = 0;
foreach ($finfo as $val) {
   $outp .= '<th>';
   $outp .= $val->name;
   $outp .= '</th>';
   $i++;
}
$outp .= '</tr>';
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $outp .= '<tr>';
    while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
            $outp .= '<td>';
            $outp .= $rs[$j];
            $outp .= '</td>';
        }
        $outp .= '</tr>';
    }
} else {
   $outp .= '<tr><td colspan =';
   $outp .= $i + 1;
   $outp .= '>';
   $outp .= "no course found";
   $outp .= '</td></tr>';
}
$outp .= '</table></div>';

mysqli_close($bd);

echo ($outp);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "only prints table head correctly" when only one row is returned?  Is the row being printed, just not with the correct HTML?

Comment: The script generate a table consists of rows that represent the courses enrolled by an applicant.  In one of the test case, the applicant enrolled exactly one course, in this case, the scipt only output the table column heading, but that course is not listed.   When the number of course enrolled is 0 or > 1, the script works fine.

Comment: My suggestion would be to output some diagnostic text to the screen.  There isn't a reason it should display more than one row, but not one row, unless the HTML isn't coming out right or there is a semantic error that isn't shown here.  Do a `var_dump` or `echo` of some information that should be displayed where the rows begin appearing and see if that helps.  Also the line `$outp .= '</tr>';` is in a place that could cause bad markup to be output.

Comment: Crackertastic - I follow your advice to output some text, the code is ok, the problem is at the html page.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to simplify the code as follow (Not parsed - please check for syntax):

```
    $result = mysqli_query($bd, $qry1);

    $outp = '<div><table><tr>';
    for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {
        $finfo = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
        $outp .= '<th>{$finfo->name}</th>';
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $outp .= '<tr>';
        while($rs = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

            foreach($rs as $col) {
                $outp .= '<td>{$col}</td>';
            }

        }
        $outp .= '</tr>';
    }
    else {
       $outp .= '<tr><td colspan =';
       $outp .= $i + 1;
       $outp .= '>';
       $outp .= "no course found";
       $outp .= '</td></tr>';
    }
    $outp .= '</table></div>';

    mysqli_close($bd);

    echo ($outp);
```

Comment: Let me know if it works. I'll try and assist until you get is working